# Google Calendar Events API for Insert throwing 400

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, http-status-code-400

I have checked out other posts related to this issue and they are not the same: I am using "response", I copied the date/time from the google api website so the format is correct, and I've played around with the headers. Any other ideas for why this is not working?

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: failed [400] {  "error": {   "errors": [    {     "domain": "global",     "reason": "required",     "message": "Missing end time."    }   ],   "code": 400,   "message": "Missing end time."  } } [object Object]
```

My code below broken down into steps: the url i'm going to POST, the user access token, the options for the inserted calendar event including headers and the event with start, end and event summary, and the actual http post and  callback function:

```
calendarSchedule() {
    if(Meteor.user() && moment(Meteor.user().services.google.expiresAt) > moment()._d) {
      var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events";
      var userAccessToken = Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken;

      var options = {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userAccessToken,
          'X-JavaScript-User-Agent': "Google APIs Explorer",
        },
        calendarId: 'primary',
        resource : {
          start: { dateTime: "2016-05-03T18:03:58+02:00" },
          end: { dateTime: "2016-05-03T18:03:58+02:00" },
          summary: "testSummar",
        }
      };

      HTTP.post(url, options,
        function(error,result) {
          console.log("posted to calendar? "+ error+ result);
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and thought I should post the answer here.

For some reason, in this case, you use data instead of resource. I'm not sure why in case someone else wants to chime in on that point, but this is different than what's on the google API calendar site.

My final code that works:

```
  calendarSchedule() {
    if(Meteor.user() && moment(Meteor.user().services.google.expiresAt) > moment()._d) {
      var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events";
      var userAccessToken = Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken;

      var currentEvent = {
        'summary': this.props.text,
        // 'location': this.refs.location.textContent,
        'start': {
          'dateTime': moment()._d,
          'timeZone': this.refs.timeZone,
        },
        'end': {
          'dateTime': moment(moment()._d).add(1, 'hours'),
          'timeZone': this.refs.timeZone,
        },
        'attendees': [],
        'reminders': {
          'useDefault': true,
        }
      };

      var options = {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userAccessToken,
          'X-JavaScript-User-Agent': "Google APIs Explorer",
        },
        calendarId: 'primary',
        data: currentEvent,
      };

      var searchResult = HTTP.post(url, options,
        function(error,result) {
          console.log("posted to calendar? "+ error+ result);
        });
    }
  }
```